# Eliminate comma after the last item in an array for c++

Tags: c++

I have a for loop that prints a comma and a space after each item in a list. It is also outputting a comma and space after the last item in the list. How do I get rid of this?

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; ++i) {
   cin >> hourlyTemp[i];
}

for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; i++) {
   cout << hourlyTemp[i];
   cout << ", ";
}
```

My output is : 90, 92, 94, 95, 
I want it to be : 90, 92, 94, 95

Comment: Use an `if` statement

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using a loop with incremented integer, this version of solution is simple and fast.

```
if(0 < NUM_VALS ) cout << hourlyTemp[0];

for (i = 1; i < NUM_VALS; i++) {
   cout << ", " << hourlyTemp[i];  
}
```